# flex: filling color in an object built using primitives

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, fill

I have a bounded object, created using primitives lines in Action Script- either an oval or a triangle. Is there any way I can fill the contents in a specific color

Just to clarify on this- the shape could be in two ways
a) drawing a isoceles triangle based on a variable apex angle
b) two curved lines to form a "lens"

I am not sure if I can use the fill function, as I am not drawing a inherently bounded shape- the closed nature is based on my calculations

```
  lensPart1=drawArc(xavlspace*0.5+radius*distancefactor*0.86,yavlspace*0.5, Math.abs(radius*distancefactor), 150/360, 60/360, 20); //function to draw an arc 
c.addChild(lensPart1);

                              lensPart2=drawArc(xavlspace*0.5+param.radius*distancefactor*0.86,yavlspace*0.5, Math.abs(radius*distancefactor), 30/360, -60/360, 20);//function to draw an arc 
c.addChild(lensPart2)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code, how you are creating "Shape"

Comment: in Flex 4 you have the fill, and the strokeColor. please add a snippet of your code, so we can help

Comment: have provided the code fragment- given I have created the bounds, is there a way for flex to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ellipse:Shape = new Shape();
ellipse.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
ellipse.graphics.drawEllipse(100, 100, 60, 110); // (x,y,width,height)
ellipse.graphics.endFill();
```

This will create an ellipse with black fill.Add the ellipse to the parent using addChild method.

Answer (score 0):

you need [beginFill](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginFill%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Use `beginFill()` and `endFill()` methods of [`flash.display.Graphics`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) class.